Exception handling at message adapter layer for pubsub
I am using the DirectChannel mechanism where my pubsub message handler kicks in. I am using the adapter route which is as below
    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapterSaasVisPoc(
            @Qualifier("myInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(
                pubSubTemplate, myConfig.getPocSubscription());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setPayloadType(MyCustomerClass.class);
        return adapter;
    }

The handler does the ack of the message in the finally block(handler is not shown here in the snippet).
However say the adapter because it relies on jackson to de-serialize fails, then my message get stuck. I am using manual ack and I want it like that. I want to still ack this message. But I am not sure how to do that at the adapter layer that in case of exception, it must ack it.
The PubSubInboundChannelAdapter swallows the exception. That is not a good practice I feel. And then it just does a nack, and the message is now stuck forever.
    private void consumeMessage(ConvertedBasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage<?> message) {
        Map<String, Object> messageHeaders = this.headerMapper.toHeaders(message.getPubsubMessage().getAttributesMap());
        messageHeaders.put("gcp_pubsub_original_message", message);

        try {
            this.sendMessage(this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(message.getPayload()).copyHeaders(messageHeaders).build());
            this.processedMessage(message.getProjectSubscriptionName());
            if (this.ackMode == AckMode.AUTO_ACK || this.ackMode == AckMode.AUTO) {
                message.ack();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException var4) {
            if (this.ackMode == AckMode.AUTO) {
                message.nack();
                this.logWarning(message, var4, "message nacked automatically.");
            } else {
                this.logWarning(message, var4, "message neither acked nor nacked.");
            }
        }

    }


